# How do I select playlists in a subfolder in Itunes using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, itunes

This code will return all the play lists in iTunes:

```
tell application "iTunes"

get name of playlists

end tell
```

How do I return all play lists in a subfolder?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set myList to {}
    set myFolder to folder playlist "testFolder"

    set myPlaylists to playlists
    repeat with aPlaylist in myPlaylists
        try
            if aPlaylist's parent = myFolder then set end of myList to aPlaylist's name
        end try
    end repeat

    return myList
end tell
```